# why are some callback functions work just calling them with "setTimeout(this.functions, 1000);" but others need to have an arrow function to work

Tags: javascript

for example i have this program calling functions some with set time outs, some function work just calling them (setTimeout(this.siguienteNivel, 1500); but others needed (the last ones of the code) an arrow function, (​setTimeout(() =>​this.iluminarSecuenciaFinal();}, 1000 * i);) if the arrow function is missing the function does not trigger in these specific cases, i dont understand why this differentiator, the program is in a class, i dont know if that makes a difference

this is a piece, the complete code is this if needed:
https://github.com/moorooba/simon/blob/master/index.html

```
>  elegirColor(ev) {
          const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color;
          const numeroColor = this.transformarColorANumero(nombreColor);
          this.iluminarColor(nombreColor);
          if (numeroColor === this.secuencia[this.subnivel]) {
            this.subnivel++;
            if (this.subnivel === this.nivel) {
              this.nivel++;
              this.eliminarEventosClick();
              if (this.nivel === ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1) {
                this.ganador();
              } else {
                setTimeout(this.siguienteNivel, 1500);
              }
            }
          } else {
            this.perdio();
          }
        }

        // ganoElJuego() {
        //   swal("Platzi", "Felicitaciones, ganaste el juego!", "success").then(
        //     this.inicializar
        //   );
        // }

        // perdioElJuego() {
        //   swal("Platzi", "Lo lamentamos, perdiste :(", "error").then(() => {
        //     this.eliminarEventosClick();
        //     this.inicializar();
        //   });
        // }

        perdio() {
          loser.classList.remove("hide");
          setTimeout(this.startos, 1000);
          this.eliminarEventosClick();
        }

        startos() {
          loser.classList.add("hide");
          boton.classList.remove("hide");
        }

        ganador() {
          console.log("diparo");
          this.eliminarEventosClick();
          for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // setTimeout(this.iluminarSecuenciaFinal, 1000 * i);
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.iluminarSecuenciaFinal();
            }, 1000 * i);
          }
          // setTimeout(this.ganoJuego, 4000);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.ganoJuego();
          }, 4000);
        }

        ganoJuego() {
          console.log("ganojuego");
          winner.classList.remove("hide");

          // setTimeout(this.restart, 1500);

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.restart();
          }, 1500);
        }
```

Comment: You need to show how `this.siguienteNivel` is defined.

Comment: And ideally, please turn this into a [mcve], which should be entirely doable. The only appecriable thing that arrow functions vs. global functions (e.g. event handlers and timeouts) effect is preserving `this`: arrow functions will use `this` _at declaration time_ whereas regular functions use `this` as it exists _at execution time_ (in the case of timeouts, `this` would be [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), which in the browser equates to `window`) And that might even be enough of a hint for you to determine the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works in JavaScript:

```js
class Foo {
  bar = 'bar';
 
  log() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
  
  method() {
    setTimeout(this.log);
    setTimeout(() => this.log());
  }
}

const obj = new Foo;

obj.method();
```

In this example, (which represents the relevant part of your code) the `method` function tries to call `log` in two different ways.

In the first one, it passes a reference to `this.log` as a parameter of `setTimeout`. The `setTimeout` function receives a function as a parameter and it has no idea of the context in which it has been declared, it's as if you extracted it from the class. In that case [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is being evaluated when the function **executes** and it evaluates to `window`. The result is `undefined` because `window.bar` is `undefined`.

In the second one, it passes an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) whose particularity is to retain [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) when it is **declared**. When it executes, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the instance of the class so the result is the same as if you called `obj.log()`. The result is `'bar'` in that case.